# How to preserve capital letters in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing a paper and am using Bibtex to create the bibliography. Everything works fine except that the capital letters in the titles of my references is not preserved in the PDF. For example, in my `.bib` file I have an item like this:

```
@article{harsanyi1988general,
  title={A General Theory of Equilibrium Selection in Games},
  author={Harsanyi, John C and Selten, Reinhard},
  journal={MIT Press Books},
  volume={1},
  year={1988},
  publisher={The MIT Press}
}
```

But the title in the PDF generated when compiled is:

`A general theory of equilibrium selection in games.`

Only the first capital letter is respected. How can I make it respect all the other ones?

If you need it, the code I have in my `.main` for creating the bibliography is:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibliography.bib}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just write the letters you want to stay as capital letter in brackets in your bib file: `{A} {G}eneral {T}herory ...`

Comment: If you want to preserve the capital letters you should put them inside keys: `{}` If you use JabRef for build your database, there is an option for do it automatically. If you'll think to change later to `biblatex` you don't need it.